# Unable to run Angular 5 project in command prompt?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Hi I have developed web application in Angular 5. I am using VS2017 and running by pressing Start button. I have Jasmine also in my project. I am running jasmine as npm test and running  successfully. Also I am trying to run my project as npm dev-build. When running this command I am getting error as

[image]

Below is my script section in package.json file.

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev-build": "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js"
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  }
```

When i run npm run dev-build below screen is coming.
[image]

Can someone help me to run the project in command line? May I know do i need to use different command or modify the package.json file? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: try `npm run dev-build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try use npm like `npm dev-build` but if you what run script you need use npm like this `npm run <script-name>` where instead `<script-name>` you pass `build-dev`. It must works.

Also you can look at the npm command usage `npm --help`. And you can see that npm have the `test` command. I fear that you run `npm test` you don't run script that you have in `package.json`

Comment: Thank you. When i run npm run dev-build i am getting some screen. I have updated above.

Comment: @Niranjan it's good output. Your build is succesful. You can find buld artifacts in folder that you specify in `webpack.config` in `output.path` property.

Comment: okay thanks. So what i was expecting is browser will open and start running index page. Is that is the expected behavior?

Comment: @Niranjan index page is entry point of you web application. If you want to see another view(for examle login page) you can try play with Angular routings, guards.

Comment: What i have understood is, there will be a html file inside dist folder, and when we click that entire application will work! Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Niranjan Yes. As I see in artifacts you doesn't have `index.html` you can add it using `HtmlWebpackPlugin`. Info about this plugin you can just find in google. Also that you don't need click to `index.html` every time when rebuild application you can use `webpack-dev-server`. Example of usage you also can find in google.

Comment: okay thanks. My project template is .net core. It contains cs files also. So Am i able to run this?

Comment: @Niranjan Sorry, I work with Angular in VS Code and I don't know how looks .net .core project with Angular in VS2017. If you want to know something other you can create new question or find already existing.